# Spark doesnt seem to use the same warehouse that Hive uses

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have started using Spark 2.0 on my Eclipse, by making a maven project and getting in all the latest dependencies. I am able to run hive queries without any problems. My concern is that Spark creates another warehouse for hive and doesn't use the data warehouse that I want. So all the hive tables that I have on my server, I'm not able to read those hive tables into my Spark datasets and do any transformations. I'm only able to create and work on new tables, but i want to read my tables in hive.

My hive-site.xml :-

```
<configuration><property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description></property>        <property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description></property><property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hiveuser</value>
  <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description></property><property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>root</value>
  <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description></property><property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hive–1.1.0/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin/spark-warehouse</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description></property></configuration>
```

Comment: Spark creates another warehouse for hive..... which hdfs path does it stores?
are you using derby db?

Comment: I want it to use the same db that normal hive uses so that i can access the default hive tables

Comment: can you share hive-site.xml

Comment: ive edited the question with hive-site.xml

Comment: @Nav_cfc Since you are using embedded spark. Just make a jdbc connection to Hive Server before you create SparkContext, and use it as you want to.

Comment: how will that allow me to use Spark on that connected database then?

Comment: Hey I am also facing the same issue. Can you please let me know how you resolved it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you are able to query from hive/beeline you cant able to query same table with spark program

- you can print all the configuration to verify like this from your spark program.

Since you are using spark 2.0 please verify the below spark session

```
val spark = SparkSession
   .builder()
   .appName("yourappname")
   .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
   .enableHiveSupport()
   .getOrCreate()
```

> SparkSession exposes “catalog” as a public instance that contains
>   methods that work with the metastore (i.e data catalog). Since these
>   methods return a Dataset, you can use Dataset API to access or view
>   data.

Also try below

```
  //fetch metadata data from the catalog
    spark.catalog.listDatabases.show(false)
    spark.catalog.listTables.show(false)
```

and then print  `spark.conf.getAll().mkString("\n"))`

you can see whether any difference in hive properties(like `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` or `hive.metastore.uris`) which were there in hive-site.xml with the above properties.

Comment: we do not mention the username when we look for the table. its the db name, but the db that exists in hive, will not exist in spark-hive.

and I do not have the option to print the configurations as you have mentioned, because Im using SparkSession instead of HiveContext, because it is Spark 2.0

Comment: were you able to try above?

Comment: Yes, i tried out today. it displays all the configurations that are related to this instance of SparkSession. If the property 'hive.metastore.warehouse.dir' is the same in both hive-site.xml that hive uses and this embedded spark program, it should be able to save it in the same database right. Coz even after specifying the same value for that property, it doesnt seem to keep the metadata in the same location and isnt accessing the hive tables via spark.

Comment: hmm, there will be certain mismatch

Comment: I doubt somewhere `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`  might have overriden

Comment: I think isn't it is the same issue. [SPARK-9944](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9944) I know that you are using spark2.0, since its related properties I think its still valid for you.

Comment: Nope it isnt the same issue. in this he has added the hive-site.xml in its classpath and executed. I'm not doing all that. Im jus specifying the metastore warehouse property and seeing if it connects to the hive database. Have you ever tried to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0):

In hive-site.xml add,

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
   <value>thrift://HOST_IP_ADDRESS:9083</value>
    <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
  </property>
```

restart hive service

and then set,

1)Copy hive-site.xml from $HIVE_CONF dir to $SPARK_CONF dir

or 
2)

```
HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc);

hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://HOST_IP_ADDRESS:9083");
```

Comment: Which $SPARK_CONF as im doing this in a maven project.. We dont have any $SPARK_CONF directory. All I do is get the spark dependencies and add in the pom and run

Comment: where is your spark installed

Comment: I dont need to install if i use its dependencies

Answer (score 0):

you should config in `spark-defaults.conf`:

`spark.sql.warehouse.dir hdfs://MA:8020/user/hive/warehouse`

From http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html

Comment: do i have to change the xml as well to use the remote hive warehouse ?